# What is recommended value for hdfs datanode cache?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

How many memory should be set for hdfs datanode caching ?
OS CentOS Linux 7.4

dfs.datanode.max.locked.memory
This determines the maximum amount of memory a DataNode will use for caching